# How to solve bad operand types for binary operater '+'

Tags: java

```
float amt = Float.parseFloat(totAmt[i]);
float grandTotal;
grandTotal = (totAmt + (amt));
```

Comment: By not trying to add a float to an array of strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
float amt=Float.parseFloat(totAmt[i]);
float grandTotal;
grandTotal = grandTotal+amt;
```

changed:

```
grandTotal = (totAmt+(amt));
```

to

```
grandTotal = grandTotal+amt;
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Replacing one compile error with another one.  I can't see how this is going to help the OP.